# Raise an exception for undefined attributes in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I need the following to raise an exception:

```
jinja2.Template("Hello {{ a.x }}").render(a={})
```

Jinja2 silently returns an empty string for `a.x`, so this renders as "Hello ".

How do I make jinja2 raise an exception on undefined attributes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from jinja2 import Template, StrictUndefined
print Template("Hello {{ a.x }}", undefined=StrictUndefined).render(a={})
```

This will raise an exception:

```
File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'x'
```

If you set a value for a.x then it will work as intended:

```
print Template("Hello {{ a.x }}", undefined=StrictUndefined).render(a={'x':42})
```

will print:

```
Hello 42
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can't because that behavior is a feature: see [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#variables)

What I would do is to write a custom filter that behaves more in a pythonic way and raises an `KeyError` in case.

Something that can be used more or less like:

```
jinja2.Template("Hello {{ a|myget('x') }}").render(a={})
```

Comment: It can actually be done, by selecting the correct 'undefined' class (see my answer).